# Doctrine doesn't store ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I have an `Entity` that has a array field like this:

```
...
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tels", type="json_array")
     */
    private $tels;
...
```

I fill this using form and it fills correctly as after submit `var_dump($entity->getTels())` returns this:

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[448]
  private '_elements' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '123' (length=3)
```

But after persist doctrine ignores this fields value and stores empty array:

```
+----+------+
| id | tels |
+----+------+
|  1 | {}   |
+----+------+
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You wrote *Doctorine* in the title.

Comment: What version of Doctrine are you using?

Comment: @Chausser: Hi ;-) | v2.4.6

Comment: what do you get running `var_dump(json_encode($entity->getTels()))`

Comment: @Chausser: `string '{}' (length=2)` !!!?!

Comment: There is your issue, you could try just using regular array type `type="array"`, unless you have a specific need for it to be a json_array?

Comment: @Chausser: you're right json only encodes arrays & not objects; so I should either use DataTransformers or regular array; thanks (& if you make an answer I will accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `json_array` expects an array which will then be converted to json using json_encode. While a Doctrine ArrayCollection is technically traversable it doesnt nicely cast to array. So you either need to call `->toArray()` on it or change your type to just be `array`

```
$entity->setTels($theArrayCollection->toArray());
```